# Как определить в слушателе на каком элементе был клик. Js

Tags: javascript, события

Как определить в слушателе на каком элементе был клик?

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="list">
    <ul class="ula">
        <li class="li">1<li>
        <li class="li">2<li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ulb">
        <li class="li">1<li>
        <li class="li">2<li>
    </ul>
</div>

/* Js */
list = document.querySelector('.list');

ula= document.querySelector('.ula');
ulb= document.querySelector('.ulb');

lia = ula.querySelectorAll('.li');
lib = ulb.querySelectorAll('.li');

list.addEventListener('click', listHandler, false);
```

Интересует именно определение в каком UL случилось событие при клике на LI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.list');

let ula = document.querySelector('.ula');
let ulb = document.querySelector('.ulb');

let lia = ula.querySelectorAll('.li');
let lib = ulb.querySelectorAll('.li');

list.addEventListener('click', listHandler, false);

function listHandler( event ){
  let parentUL = event.target.closest('ul');
  if( parentUL === ula ) console.log('A');
  if( parentUL === ulb ) console.log('B');
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <ul class="ula">
        <li class="li">1<li>
        <li class="li">2<li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ulb">
        <li class="li">1<li>
        <li class="li">2<li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Элементарно) Спасибо!